# PhoneGap: Save Image from Canvas to Local Image Gallery?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have a PhoneGap/Cordova App running on Android/iOS. The App creates an image in a HTML5 canvas element. This canvas is exported in the browser to an image.

**How can I save an image generated in the browser to the Android/iOS local image gallery?**

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the custom plugin for iOS [Canvas2ImagePlugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin) . which will pass image from phonegap  to native (objective C). To save image into photo album

In your iOs project add 2 files SaveToPhotoAlbum.h and SaveToPhotoAlbum.m

**SaveToPhotoAlbum.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>


@interface SaveToPhotoAlbum : CDVPlugin {
}

- (void) saveToPhotoAlbum:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

**SaveToPhotoAlbum.m**

```
#import "SaveToPhotoAlbum.h"

@implementation SaveToPhotoAlbum

- (void) saveToPhotoAlbum:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    NSString* callbackId = [arguments pop];
    NSString* path = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    path = [(NSString *)path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
    path = [path stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];

    UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];

    //Now it will do this for each photo in the array
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
}

@end
```

**saveToPhotoAlbum.js**

```
(function(cordova) {

/**
 * Constructor
 */
function SaveToPhotoAlbum() {}


SaveToPhotoAlbum.prototype.saveToPhotoAlbum = function(successCallback, failCallback, uri) {
    console.log('SaveToPhotoAlbum.js: saveToPhotoAlbum: uri:' + uri);
    if (!uri) {
        if (typeof failCallback === 'function') {
            failCallback('uri not provided');
        }
        return;
    }

    cordova.exec(
        successCallback,
        failCallback,
        "SaveToPhotoAlbum",
        "saveToPhotoAlbum",
        [uri]
    );
};

/**
 * Install function
 */
SaveToPhotoAlbum.install = function() {
    if ( !window.plugins ) {
        window.plugins = {};
    } 
    if ( !window.plugins.SaveToPhotoAlbum ) {
        window.plugins.SaveToPhotoAlbum = new SaveToPhotoAlbum();
    }
};

/**
 * Add to Cordova constructor
 */
if (cordova && cordova.addConstructor) {
    cordova.addConstructor(SaveToPhotoAlbum.install);
} else {
    console.log("SaveToPhotoAlbum Cordova Plugin could not be installed.");
    return null;
}

})(window.PhoneGap || window.Cordova || window.cordova);
```

and call in your html file as:

```
 var imageSource = $('#widgetScreen_widgetContainer [name="mobileimage_66"]')[0].src;
            window.plugins.SaveToPhotoAlbum.saveToPhotoAlbum(photoSuccess, photoFail, imageSource);
```

Comment: What do I use if I don't have a canvas but still have an mms image to save?

Comment: canvas2image  is the name of the plugin , but it saves local or remote image into iOS saved albums

Comment: How can I use this plugin to save an image which was created with var image = new Image(); ?